# T-SQL Convert UTC time from cloud server to local time with daylight savings

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, datetime-conversion

I have an Azure cloud SQL DB located in UTC timezone, but I'm located in Central Europe with daylight savings half of the year. In an ETL process I use GETDATE() to fill a column to tell me the last datetime my data was refreshed. Because the machine this is done at is in UTC, the result from GETDATE differs from the time in my physical location.

I've searched for solutions but the two most suggested solutions do not seem to work. Firstly to use GETUTCDATE and GETDATE to determine the difference and use this will not work because both functions return the same datetime. The function AT TIME ZONE will not work because half the year my timezone is Central European Time (CET), the other half in Central European Summer Time (CEST). The date the zones switch is different each year so I cannot use a check to see if the date is between two dates.

I feel there should be some solution for this I haven't thought of yet, as I cannot be the first to encounter this. Curious if someone has a fix. Thanks in advance!

Found two solutions as described above, but logically they would not work due to the cirumstances. Haven't found a solution which solves this in a fairly easy manner.

Comment: Well, `AT TIME ZONE` works fine, it's just that the timezone names are confusing. `SELECT getutcdate() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time';` -> this will correctly return summer time if you send a date from 6 months ago (try `DATEADDD(MONTH, -6, getutcdate())`).

Comment: I wrote a series of posts about using a calendar table for this: [1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3173/handle-conversion-between-time-zones-in-sql-server-part-1/) [2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3174/handle-conversion-between-time-zones-in-sql-server-part-2/) [3](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3175/handle-conversion-between-time-zones-in-sql-server-part-3/)

Comment: @AaronBertrand any chance of persuading the SQL Server team to use IANA tzdb like everyone else?

Comment: Isn't it better to save time as utc in your local server as well

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks a lot! This solution worked. I incorrectly assumed SQL would need two different Time zones for our summer and winter time, but the Central Europe Standard Time indeed works for both summer and winter time. I tested via your suggested -6 months and saw the extra hour. We will use this in our code. Thanks again1

Comment: Yeah, I complained about this during the beta period when the feature was first introduced, but my comments fell on dead ears. `Central Europe Time` would have been far less confusing, for example. I think a lot of people abandon the feature almost immediately when they only see "standard" time for their time zone (either because it shouldn't force standard or because daylight is missing).